# Can't read from a .env file

Tags: python, environment-variables, dotenv

I'm new to python, and I am trying to build a little Reddit bot to get some practice.
My bot works just fine (tested many times) but once I try to move the credentials to a .env file it fails.

I've ran `pip3 install python-dotenv`

```
This is my code, just one file, removing irrelevant stuff:
import os
import praw
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import db
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()

cred = credentials.Certificate("serviceAccountKey.json")
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, {
    'databaseURL': 'https://makideat-6a-default-db.firebaseio.com'
})
db_ref = db.reference()

reddit = praw.Reddit(
    client_id=os.getenv('CLIENT_ID'),
    client_secret=os.getenv('CLIENT_SECRET'),
    username=os.getenv('USERNAME'),
    password=os.getenv('PASSWORD'),
    user_agent=os.getenv('USER_AGENT')
)


def summoned_reply(comment):
    DO SOME STUFF...



messages = reddit.inbox.stream()  # creates an iterable for your inbox and streams it
for message in messages:  # iterates through your messages
    try:
        if message in reddit.inbox.mentions() and message in reddit.inbox.unread():
            summoned_reply(message)
            message.mark_read()
    except praw.exceptions.APIException:
        print("probably a rate limit....")
```

And this is the error I'm getting (line 56 is `for message in messages:`):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Yanay\Documents\Coding\NiceAndPretty\main.py", line 56, in <module>
    for message in messages:  # iterates through your messages
  File "C:\Users\Yanay\.virtualenvs\NiceAndPretty\lib\site-packages\praw\models\util.py", line 195, in stream_generator
    for item in reversed(list(function(limit=limit, **function_kwargs))):
  File "C:\Users\Yanay\.virtualenvs\NiceAndPretty\lib\site-packages\praw\models\listing\generator.py", line 63, in __next__
    self._next_batch()
  File "C:\Users\Yanay\.virtualenvs\NiceAndPretty\lib\site-packages\praw\models\listing\generator.py", line 89, in _next_batch
    self._listing = self._reddit.get(self.url, params=self.params)
  File "C:\Users\Yanay\.virtualenvs\NiceAndPretty\lib\site-packages\praw\util\deprecate_args.py", line 43, in wrapped
    return func(**dict(zip(_old_args, args)), **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Yanay\.virtualenvs\NiceAndPretty\lib\site-packages\praw\reddit.py", line 634, in get
    return self._objectify_request(method="GET", params=params, path=path)
  File "C:\Users\Yanay\.virtualenvs\NiceAndPretty\lib\site-packages\praw\reddit.py", line 739, in _objectify_request
    self.request(
  File "C:\Users\Yanay\.virtualenvs\NiceAndPretty\lib\site-packages\praw\util\deprecate_args.py", line 43, in wrapped
    return func(**dict(zip(_old_args, args)), **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Yanay\.virtualenvs\NiceAndPretty\lib\site-packages\praw\reddit.py", line 941, in request
    return self._core.request(
  File "C:\Users\Yanay\.virtualenvs\NiceAndPretty\lib\site-packages\prawcore\sessions.py", line 330, in request
    return self._request_with_retries(
  File "C:\Users\Yanay\.virtualenvs\NiceAndPretty\lib\site-packages\prawcore\sessions.py", line 228, in _request_with_retries
    response, saved_exception = self._make_request(
  File "C:\Users\Yanay\.virtualenvs\NiceAndPretty\lib\site-packages\prawcore\sessions.py", line 185, in _make_request
    response = self._rate_limiter.call(
  File "C:\Users\Yanay\.virtualenvs\NiceAndPretty\lib\site-packages\prawcore\rate_limit.py", line 33, in call
    kwargs["headers"] = set_header_callback()
  File "C:\Users\Yanay\.virtualenvs\NiceAndPretty\lib\site-packages\prawcore\sessions.py", line 283, in _set_header_callback
    self._authorizer.refresh()
  File "C:\Users\Yanay\.virtualenvs\NiceAndPretty\lib\site-packages\prawcore\auth.py", line 425, in refresh
    self._request_token(
  File "C:\Users\Yanay\.virtualenvs\NiceAndPretty\lib\site-packages\prawcore\auth.py", line 158, in _request_token
    raise OAuthException(
prawcore.exceptions.OAuthException: invalid_grant error processing request
```

Then, in the same directory I have a `.env` file in the following structure (changed characters for everything here of course, but haven't changed the structure or added or removed spaces from anywhere):

```
CLIENT_ID=gGATUW-Ea507LoQ
CLIENT_SECRET=_b6vCCHKBCqVHzlJin3sEQ
USERNAME=Maddeeat
PASSWORD=!Neatat!
USER_AGENT=Maddeeat:1.0.0 (by u/Maddeeat)
```

Comment: maybe you have file `.env` in different folder, or you run code from different folder. Maybe first use `print()` to see what you get with `os.getenv('CLIENT_ID'`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Printing helped .I had a different "username" variable saved in my system which messed with the login details.